# Double-answer from aiogram + telethon

Tags: python, api, telethon, aiogram, aio-mysql

I have two scripts, which are written on telethon and aiogram. My telethon scripts resend massages from the groups and aiogram process them (will be completed later). Unfortunately, when both of scripts are executing simultaneously, that cause issues: aiogram responds to the resented message twice. I TRIED to make docker-containers and even run both of script on separate machines, but issue still persist. When only aiogram is running without telethon - everything is okey.

aiogram script:

```
import aiogram
import aiomysql
import asyncio
from aiogram import types, Bot, Dispatcher, executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.types import Update
from aiogram.types.chat_member import ChatMemberMember, ChatMemberOwner, ChatMemberAdministrator
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
#from keyboard import get_inline_keyboard

TOKEN_API = "token)"
processed_messages = {}

storage = MemoryStorage()
bot = aiogram.Bot(TOKEN_API)
dp = aiogram.Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

@dp.message_handler()
async def process_forwarded_message(message: types.Message):
    
    if message.message_id in processed_messages:
        return
    
    processed_messages[message.message_id] = True

        
    buttons = [
        aiogram.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Edit", callback_data=f"edit:{message.message_id}"),
        aiogram.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Delete", callback_data=f"delete:{message.message_id}"),
        aiogram.types.InlineKeyboardButton("Forward", callback_data=f"forward:{message.message_id}")
    ]
    keyboard = aiogram.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(*buttons)
    
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                           text=message.text,
                           reply_markup=keyboard)
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, 
                           skip_updates=True)
```

telethon script

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
import aiogram
import aiomysql

Id_bot =
Id_Group2 = 
Id_Group3 = 
Id_Group4 = 
Id_Group5 = 
Id_Group6 = 
api_id = ''
api_hash = ''

chats_to_listen_to = [Id_Group2, Id_Group3, Id_Group4, Id_Group5, Id_Group6]

client = TelegramClient('none', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chats_to_listen_to))
async def new_message_handler(event):
    if event.grouped_id:
        return    # ignore messages that are gallery here

    await client.send_message(Id_bot, event.message)

@client.on(events.Album(chats=chats_to_listen_to))
async def album_handler(event):
    await event.forward_to(entity=Id_bot, message=event.message)

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: I think both your scripts are running concurrently

Comment: What do you mean? I need this to scripts to work concurrently

Comment: You have to determine a way for the scripts to communicate or share state, to ensure that each message is only processed once

Comment: I even made a middleware, it does not work: class ProcessedMessagesMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    async def on_pre_process_message(self, message: types.Message, data: dict):
        if message.message_id in processed_messages:
            raise CancelHandler()

dp.middleware.setup(ProcessedMessagesMiddleware())

@dp.message_handler()
async def process_forwarded_message(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    processed_messages.add(message.message_id)